# Stop tar after tape error

Tags: linux, tar

I am trying to extract files from a tape device using `tar` and am getting IO errors:

```
tar: /dev/nst0: Cannot read: Input/output error
```

However, `tar` tries to continue anyway:

```
tar: Skipping to next header
```

Is there a way to tell `tar` to exit directly after the first occurrence of the `Cannot read` error? I worked my way through the man pages and the `tar` manual, but could not find anything like that. Or is there a way to catch the error message in the calling shell and kill `tar` from outside?

The OS is Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0-38 and `tar` is GNU tar 1.28.

Comment: Which OS and which tar implementation are you using?

Comment: The OS is Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0-38 and tar is GNU tar 1.28.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# Timeout: 10000 seconds
set timeout 10000

spawn tar your tar args come here
# spawn custom-tar-script.sh

expect "tar: /dev/nst0: Cannot read: Input/output error"

send_user "Will kill PID <[exp_pid]>.\n"
exec kill [exp_pid]
# exec killall tar
# exec custom-kill-script.sh
close
```

(Adapt it to your needs)

Comment: Thanks, looks like this does the "killing from outside" that I had in mind. When the `timeout` is over does it terminate the spawned script?

Comment: Yes, for that reason I increased the timeout (~10 seconds is default).